# Get Tilemill to show openstreetmap map with english Titles

Tags: ios, openstreetmap, mapbox, tilemill

My goal is to get a offline map for mapbox iOS application to show a map of jerusalem with english streetnames. The problem is that all my street names shows up i hebrew.
Is there anyway to export an openstreetmap to osm containing the english name tags not the default showing hebrew.
Is there a way to get tilemill to render the map using the english tags "name:en" ?
I managed to get the online tool of mapbox to render it with english but that one u cant export to osm ?

Answer (score 0):

OpenStreetMap supports [localized names via the name tag](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Names#Localization). The default name is usually the name preferred locally. By using an *ISO 639-1* suffix names of other languages can be specified, e.g. *name:en* for english and *name:he* for hebrew. Your export should already contain such localized name tags.

I've never used TileMill so far but you should be able to use these localized names by modifying your rendering stylesheet. Instead of *name* (the name used locally) the stylesheet just has to use *name:en*.